# mime-type autodetection of .js file fails for http upload in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, forms, upload

i'm using a http upload for transferring a javascript file to the server. however, firefox sends the content with the mime type set to 'x-c'. opera 11 is better in assuming  'application/x-javascript' but still incorrect.
   as i'd prefer to avoid server-side mime type detection, is there any chance to override mime-type detection for specific file extensions (namely '.js') or to provide hints to the browser algorithm ?

the ideal solution would be cross-browser ( at least ff 3.6, ie8, chrome 8 should be supported ). however, as a first step a solution limited to firefox would be welcome, too.

platform details:
ff 3.6.13 on winxp sp3

uploaded file:
jquery 1.4.4 ( uncompressed and minified versions ), elementary test files
all files have the .js extension

thanks in advance for your efforts.

best regards, carsten

Comment: This needs to be solved on server side. What language are you using there?

Comment: perl and plsql. the web app is served by apache/mod_perl.

Comment: hello everybody, meanwhile i've resorted to server-side mapping of the pair of file extension and detected mime type onto the desired mime-type, possibly extending the domain to include the user agent at a later stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now with html5 you can read file properties using the JavaScript File API, this way you can do things like checking the MIME type, the name or the file size. Unfortunately its only available in Firefox and Chrome fir the moment.

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />

var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
```

then you can check the file properties with

```
file.name // The file name
file.size // The file size in bytes
file.type // The MIME-Type Eje:'audio/mp3'
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. however, ie and chrome support are still mandatory, and safari joined the circle of target clients. anyway, the file api seems the way to go (though we have opted for a server-side scheme). regards, carsten